# Why the last .then works in promise chaining

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. In the following code, I haven't returned anything from the .then method. So, as expected .then will not work. My question is, why last .then (blue color) work instead of first .then (red color).

```js
let bodyBgChange = (color, delay) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
            resolve()
        }, delay)
        
    })
}

bodyBgChange('green',1000)
    .then(()=>{ 
        bodyBgChange('red', 1000)
    })
    .then(()=>{
        bodyBgChange('yellow', 1000)
    })
    .then(()=>{
        bodyBgChange('pink', 1000)
    })
    .then(()=>{
        bodyBgChange('blue', 1000)
    })
```

Comment: The `.then()` will always return a promise however if you return a synchronous value it will just push it to the microtask queue ASAP as is. By using no `return` instruction you are forcing the `.then()` to return a promisified synchronous value which is `undefined`. So while you place several paint orders they all stack up in the animation frame queue and get painted in every 1/60 secs (~17ms) at once hence you only see the last one.

Answer (score 3):

You forget the [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) or use the arrow function's [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body)

```js
let bodyBgChange = (color, delay) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
      resolve()
    }, delay)

  })
}

bodyBgChange('green', 1000)
  .then(() => {
    return bodyBgChange('red', 1000)
  })
  .then(() => {
    return bodyBgChange('yellow', 1000)
  })
  .then(() => {
    return bodyBgChange('pink', 1000)
  })
  .then(() => {
    return bodyBgChange('blue', 1000)
  })
```

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your answer. I intentionally omitted the return keyword.  My question was why the last .then works without the return keyword. Shouldn't the first .then work if I don't use the return keyword?

Answer (score 0):

It just run every *then* block if no error occur.

> Here's the magic: the then() function returns a new promise, different
> from the original:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Really a black magic.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding `then` here.

Each of your `then` hooks is called, regardless if they return a value.
And seeing as each of them have the same timer set to them it'll seem like only the last hook is "working".
Returning values in your then hook will pass on that value to the next then hook which should result in the behavior you were expecting in this case.

```
let bodyBgChange = (color, delay) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
      resolve()
    }, delay)
  })
}

bodyBgChange('green', 1000)
  .then(() => {
    return bodyBgChange('red', 1000)
  })
  .then(() => {
    return bodyBgChange('yellow', 1000)
  })
  .then(() => {
    return bodyBgChange('pink', 1000)
  })
  .then(() => {
    return 'foo'
  })
  .then((val) => {
    // val === 'foo'
  }
```

Comment: Understood now. Many thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)